# Expression similar to 'freak out'

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

For usage like this:

> I *freaked out* when I saw that file was not there.
>
> Every time I talk to him, he *freaks me out* by his strange stories.

What similar expressions can I use instead of '*freak out*'?

Comment: *Losing it* ?! As in, "he *lost it* when he saw that file wasn't there".

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is too vague for a pinpoint answer.

In other words, ***why*** did you freak out when that file was missing? Did you lose a lot of work? (Was it anger?) Were you going to miss an important deadline? (Was it frustration?) Did you think someone had stolen sensitive information? (Was it fear?)

A person can “freak out” because of excitement:

> *Paco freaked out when Mexico won in overtime.*

fear:

> *During the movie, I freaked out when that ghost reached out and grabbed her.*

anger:

> *I freaked out when that guy scratched my car!*

frustration:

> *Dave freaked out when he realized he left that report at home on his desk.*

grief:

> *She freaked out when she saw her nephew's name among the list of victims.*

or unnerving aversion:

> *I was freaked out by the way my brother-in-law was staring at me*.

Once you can identify the emotion that's causing the reaction, that can open up several options, some of them idiomatic, to describe the excitement:

> *Paco **went nuts** when Mexico won in overtime.*

fear:

> *During the movie, I **jumped out of my seat** when that ghost reached out and grabbed her.*

anger:

> *I **was pissed** when that guy scratched my car!*

frustration:

> *Dave **was kicking himself** when he realized he left that report at home on his desk.*

grief:

> *She **beat her chest** when she saw her nephew's name among the list of victims.*

or unnerving aversion:

> *I **got the chills** by the way my brother-in-law was staring at me*.

Of these, I think that *went nuts* (or *went crazy*) are perhaps the most flexible. Much like *freaked out*, those can be used in a wide array of contexts. However, I've only scratched the surface here, and I'd expect we could come up with several other candidates worthy of consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You can say  “It really knocked me for six when I saw that file was not there” ([1](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+for+six)) or  “I was totally devastated when I saw that file was not there”.  One sense of *[devastated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devastated#Adjective)* is “Extremely upset and shocked”.  For that matter, you could say  “I was [shocked, shocked!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjbPi00k_ME) when I saw that file was not there”.

*Lost it* was mentioned in a comment.  Idiomatic *[almost lost it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/almost+lost+it)*, *[bent out of shape](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Bent+Out+of+Shape)*,  *[fall to pieces](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+to+pieces)*, and *[go to pieces](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+pieces)*  can be used as in the following examples, which thefreedictionary.com attributes to McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

> I was so mad, I almost lost it.
>   When he saw the dent in his fender, he almost lost it.
>   I got bent out of shape because of the way I was treated.
>   I was so nervous, I fell to pieces and couldn't give my speech.
>   Roger fell to pieces when his mother died.
>   Poor Jane went to pieces after her divorce.
>   Fred went to pieces during the trial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word "perturb" fits the bill in this case, both in a passive and active sense.

```
I was perturbed when I saw the file was missing.

His strange stories perturbed me.
```

There are also many other words and phrases you could use but not necessarily in both situations - e.g. `make my skin crawl` would apply to the strange stories, but not perhaps a missing file.

Answer (score 1):

You could say, you *got the shit scared out of you*.

Answer (score 0):

I think **gross out** fits well in the scenario.

**I was Grossed out when I saw the file was missing.**

**His strange stories grossed out me.**

Or you could also use **cark** in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think "screwed" will fit well. E.g.
**I got screwed when I saw the file was missing.**